# how to translate "where (r.value1 - r.value2 > 0.01)" to NHibernate

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate, comparison

I'm converting an MSSQL query to NHibernate. In essence, this is my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable as T
WHERE (T.Value1 - T.Value2 > 0.01)
```

And this is my C# code:

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<MyType> ()
    .Where(r => (r.Value1 - r.Value2 > 0.01));
```

and it's giving me an exception:

```
Could not determine member from (r.Value1 - r.Value2)
```

I'm sure there's a way to let the database do the calculation. Does anyone know?

Comment: I think you may need to go down to ICriteria or even to HQL here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading back on this, I wanted to share the solution that ended up in production: mapping a readonly formula in FluentNHibernate.

the model needs to have a Property like this:

`public virtual decimal Difference { get { return Value2 - Value1; } protected set; }`

and this property should be mapped as follows:

`Map(x => x.Difference).Formula("(Value2 - Value1)").Readonly();`

the string parameter of the Formula method ends up in the SQL Select query, similar to this :

`Select Id, Value1, Value2, (Value2 - Value1) from MyTable...`

Note that the calculated property needs to have a protected setter or NHibernate will throw an exception saying that no setter is available.

Answer (score 1):

Predicates within QueryOver.Where() can generally only be very simple comparison expressions. QueryOver dos not support arithmetic operations within delegates (r.Value1 - r.Value2). As @Rippo has pointed out You need to fallback to ICriterion.

```
.QueryOver<MyType>()
    .Where(
        Expression.Gt(
          Projections.SqlProjection("{{alias}}.rValue1 - {{alias}}.rValue2", null, null), 
          0.01
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql query you use "MyTable" but in QueryOver: "MyType"

Comment: yep, and in real life I'm using even different values, so it's probably for the best that this is ***just an example***
Besides, any programmer who prefixes their variables with My should be shot or at least fired. But this is all irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Yet, you are right. Look at "NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions" and "NHibernate.Criterion.Expression", possibly it's help.